# Cell highlighting for the GMGridView

Tags: ios, gmgridview, gmgridviewcell

I'm using the [`GMGridView`](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) with a subclassed `UIView` as the `contentView` of the cells. These are assigned in the

```
- (GMGridViewCell *)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

Now I'd like the cells to have a highlight, similar to the behavior of the `UIButton`. Meaning that there is a slightly opaque darker overlay. I just can't figure out where I'd have to assign the highlighting.

I saw that `GMGridViewCell` has a property called `highlighted`, which indicates if the cell ist highlighted or not. Setting it to `cell.highlighted = YES;` in the above method doesn't change anything in the appearance of the cell.

In the description on the `GMGridView` website it says

> **Features - General:**
>
> > - Cell highlighting support

So, there should be a way ...

Can anybody tell me, how the highlighting should be assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate it when this happens. Just found the answer.

Apparently the highlighting will be applied to the subviews of `cell.contentView`, which can be seen here [in the commit](https://github.com/futuretap/GMGridView/commit/0135d17f6938b6b458989f5fb81f001a67e94c30).

The cell will be set highlighted while touched:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.highlighted = YES;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.highlighted = NO;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.highlighted = NO;
}
```

And then the subviews' highlight state will be activated.

```
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)aHighlighted {
    highlighted = aHighlighted;

    [self.contentView recursiveEnumerateSubviewsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(setHighlighted:)]) {
            [(UIControl*)view setHighlighted:highlighted];
        }
    }];
}
```

So, to realize cell highlighting, I just had to add an `UIImageView` with the transparent layer above the parts of my custom cell view. Hope this helps anyone.